# How to find the low & high in Merge Sort

Tags: c++, algorithm, mergesort

I have a basic understanding of the Merge Sort algorithm. But for some reason I can't wrap my head around where the values from low and high are coming from. This is the code I am working with for Merge.

```
void practiceMerge(int a[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[10000];
    int i = low, j = mid + 1, k = 0;

    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            b[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    while (i <= mid)
    b[k++] = a[i++];

    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = a[j++];

    k--;
    while (k >= 0) {
        a[low + k] = b[k];
        k--;
    }
}
```

Comment: _"where the values from low and high are coming from"_ They need to be provided from the calling function. Check the sample [here](http://rosettacode.org/wiki/Sorting_algorithms/Merge_sort#C.2B.2B).

Comment: So in te calling function the numbers originate. But what I'm getting at is, do I need use, for example a Min/Max function to determine those values. Obviously I can't hard code those values. I apologize if I'm being difficult, but I do appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let me explain by commenting your code:

```
//Sort an array a from its index low to its index high by merging two
//subarrays of a that go from low to mid and mid to high.
void practiceMerge(int a[], int low, int mid, int high)
{
    int b[10000]; //Buffer
    int i = low; //starting index in first sub array
    int j = mid + 1; //starting index in second sub array
    int k = 0; //starting index in buffer

    //While you DO NOT go beyond the limit of the first subarray
    //nor the second
    while (i <= mid && j <= high) {
        if (a[i] <= a[j])
            //Put the value of the first subarray, and move 
            b[k++] = a[i++];
        else
            //Put the value of the first subarray, and move
            b[k++] = a[j++];
    }
    //Finish copying first subarray if not done yet
    while (i <= mid)
    b[k++] = a[i++];
    //Finish copying second subarray if not done yet
    while (j <= high)
        b[k++] = a[j++];

    //Copy buffer to array a
    k--;
    while (k >= 0) {
        a[low + k] = b[k];
        k--;
    }
}
```

Basically, the low, mid and high, are the borders of the array "a" that you are looking at. "a" could be bigger. Ex:

```
a =  3 2 1 5 6 7 0 1 
low = 0
mid = 2
high = 4
```

Here you are sorting the first half of a.

EDIT:
Your function merges the arrays. The main merge sort function, **splits** the array. It would be:

```
void merge_sort(int a[], int lo, int hi) {
   if (low >= hi)
      return; //Nothing to sort
   int mid = (lo+hi)/2; //The guy between lo and hi.
   merge_sort(a,lo, mid); //sort the left
   merge_sort(a, mid, hi); //sort the right
   practiceMerge(a, lo, mid, hi); //This merges the array
}
```

To understand (don't just copy paste!) think of it this way: merge_sort sorts a chunk of array, not the entire array, just the bit between lo and hi. In order to do so, it sorts one half, then the other. Then it merges that result into the array. Therefore, Inside merge_sort, the "hi" and "lo" are computed from the parameter. Now, YOU, THE USER, might want to sort the array from 0 to the end, or from 10th to 99th index. That is your choice. And that is the parameters you pass to your call.

```
void main() {
   //Bla bla bla
   merge_sort(songs, 89, 250); //Only sort some songs
}
```

Think of this, as a black box. You call it with some parameters, the box does its thing. Because the box uses itself, it knows how to call itself (i.e. it know how to compute low, high and mid) but the initial call in the recursion is your responsability as the user.

P.S.: I feel like Im not being very clear...

Comment: Much appreciated for the thorough answer. What I am confused about is, in regards to the low and the high. Do I need to find those externally (outside of the mergesort?). I'm not sure how to go about finding those two values to initiate the sorting. I may be glossing over the simple fact of how to find them.

Comment: Let me elaborate a bit more in my answer, I am editing it now.

Comment: This helped out a lot and your explanation was great. Just as a heads up, it was all very clear. Thanks again for the help.